# Gulp creates a new dist folder

Tags: javascript, web, webpack, gulp

When building the project, gulp copies the modified file into a new dist folder. 'Dev' is appended to this file name.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFmMD.png)

All this is normally compiled into the main, main dist folder, but if you work with the assembly for a long time, a lot of such new folders appear. How can you fix this?

Gulpfile:

```js
"use strict";

const gulp = require("gulp");
const webpack = require("webpack-stream");
const browsersync = require("browser-sync");

const dist = "./dist/";

gulp.task("copy-html", () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/index.html")
                .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
                .pipe(browsersync.stream());
});

gulp.task("build-js", () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/js/main.js")
                .pipe(webpack({
                    mode: 'development',
                    output: {
                        filename: 'script.js'
                    },
                    watch: false,
                    devtool: "source-map",
                    module: {
                        rules: [
                          {
                            test: /\.m?js$/,
                            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                            use: {
                              loader: 'babel-loader',
                              options: {
                                presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
                                    debug: true,
                                    corejs: 3,
                                    useBuiltIns: "usage"
                                }]]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
                .on("end", browsersync.reload);
});

gulp.task("copy-assets", () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/assets/**/*.*")
                .pipe(gulp.dest(dist + "/assets"))
                .on("end", browsersync.reload);
});

gulp.task("watch", () => {
    browsersync.init({
        server: "./dist/",
        port: 4000,
        notify: true
    });
    
    gulp.watch("./src/index.html", gulp.parallel("copy-html"));
    gulp.watch("./src/assets/**/*.*", gulp.parallel("copy-assets"));
    gulp.watch("./src/js/**/*.js", gulp.parallel("build-js"));
});

gulp.task("build", gulp.parallel("copy-html", "copy-assets", "build-js"));

gulp.task("build-prod-js", () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/js/main.js")
                .pipe(webpack({
                    mode: 'production',
                    output: {
                        filename: 'script.js'
                    },
                    module: {
                        rules: [
                          {
                            test: /\.m?js$/,
                            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                            use: {
                              loader: 'babel-loader',
                              options: {
                                presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
                                    corejs: 3,
                                    useBuiltIns: "usage"
                                }]]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel("watch", "build"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the "Compile Hero" plugin for VS Code.